# target a div without a class or id

Tags: html, css

Does any one know how I can target a div, and style it, when it is in another div and it has no id or class.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
    </div>

    <div>
    </div>

    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I target div two for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
  //css rules for a div that is the first child of .wrapper
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  //css rules for a div that is the second child of .wrapper
}
```

Note the > is necessary, otherwise it will target any descendent divs (grandchildren, etc) instead of just direct children.

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

`nth-child` allows you to select specific items. There is also `first-child` and `last-child` for selecting the first/last item.

The number **2** can also be a function like `3n+0`. This selects every third item starting from 0. Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/waZoaX) for an example.

Last but not least, you also have `nth-of-type(2)`. This will change every second item every time the same pattern appears. I have also included an example in the same [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/waZoaX).

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Whatever number you pass into the nth-child targets #wrappers specific children.
So the second div in your case.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Descendant Selectors are the Worst, not only is this not performant but it is fragile, as changes to the HTML can easily break your CSS. It is preferable to simply create a new CSS class selector.

```
// bad
.wrapper div {..}

// good
.inner-div {..}
.selecting-this {..}
.or-this {..}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner-div">
    </div>

    <div class="selecting-this">
    </div>

    <div class="or-this">
    </div> 

    <div class="inner-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

But if you can't modified the html:

```
.wrapper div {..}
```

if there is space in selector, it searches for children elements with tag `div`  INSIDE element with given class `.wrapper`

Check this out fore more information. http://modernweb.com/2013/08/12/writing-better-css/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: This is very true. Unfortunately sometimes (when using Wordpress plugins for instance) we can be in a situation where we have no control over the HTML output of the thing we need to style. In my case, it's a directory plugin that spits out trash like this as dividers: `<div style="height:15px;"></div>`